# Exception occured: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: dart

I'm tried all but really, I don't get it. It is something that is driving me crazy.

In this part of the code I can get the information from a list called articles. Look at the attached image to understand the tree.

```
ResponseTopHeadlinesNews _$ResponseTopHeadlinesNewsFromJson(
    Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return ResponseTopHeadlinesNews(
    (json['articles'] as List)
        ?.map((e) =>
            e == null ? null : Article.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
        ?.toList(),
  );
}
```

[JSON TREE VIEW 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoHG4.png)

In this second case how do I get the information starting from the root of the JSON tree? Look the second image of second tree.

[JSON TREE VIEW 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDO5r.png)

```
ResponseTopHeadlinesNews _$ResponseTopHeadlinesNewsFromJson(
    Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return ResponseTopHeadlinesNews(
    (json as List)
        ?.map((e) =>
            e == null ? null : Article.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
        ?.toList(),
  );
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: You can see on the icon at JSON in the two images that in the first example the type is marked with `{}` which means it is a `Map` and in the second example `[]` which means `List`. So the signature of your second example is wrong since it is not `Map<String, dynamic> json` but should be `List<dynamic> json` which also makes more sense since you are doing `json as List` later in the code.

Comment: julemand101 Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As also posted as a comment:

You can see on the icon at JSON in the two images that in the first example the type is marked with `{}` which means it is a Map and in the second example `[]` which means `List`. So the signature of your second example is wrong since it is not `Map<String, dynamic> json` but should be `List<dynamic> json` which also makes more sense since you are doing `json as List` later in the code.